# Git checkout map destination

Tags: git

I have a deploy to my server with git hook "post-update". 
It hook calls: "git --work-tree=/folderdestination/ checkout -f master" and it works fine

It can't change git repo. But I need to deploy the files inside project  folder www on / of the work tree checkout.

Ex:
www/index.php (of my git) --> /index.php (of my sever)

Answer (score 0):

You may achive this by doing a sparse checkout. Run this on the remote server, in the directory of the bare repo:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "www/*" >> info/sparse-checkout
```

Do a checkout to a selected destination (like what you already have) in your post-update hook:

```
git --work-tree=/ checkout -f master
mv /www/* /                      
rm -rf /www
```

Assuming you have permission to write to the root-directory will this  place the content of your `www` in the root-directory of your remote server on each push.

Comment: jordan, is interesting, but this only checkout the files listed in info/sparse-checkout. Don't change destination path. It put the folder www of the repo inside / of the server. I need to put the files inside www folder repo on / without www folder. I need mapping files to checkout and it destination folder

Comment: @David, sorry, I missed to include the last part of my hook. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Other possibility is to make a checkout in a temporany directory and later sync the files I need with rsync in the correct path.